# Five exponentials theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

The six exponentials theorem is proved in most textbooks on transcendental number theory, and the four exponent conjecture is an open problem.

**Is there any good/accessible exposition of the five exponentials theorem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waldschmidt, M.: On the transcendence methods of Gel'fond and Schneider in several variables. New advances in transcendence theory
(Durham, 1986), 375-398, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge-New York,
1988

Waldschmidt, M.: Diophantine Approximation on Linear Algebraic Groups. Transcendence Properties of the Exponential Function in Several Variables. Springer, Berlin/Heidelberg, 2000

https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/texts.html